# SOLR - delta import not with last_modified

Tags: full-text-search, solr

I saw only ways using delta import with last_modified. Is there some other ways to do delta_imports withut using timestamps? For example, if i have unique key(integer), can i tell SOLR to index only those, which are greater then my last unique key?

Answer (score 0):

So you could definitely hack this in yourself.  However, what about if you manipulate an existing row?  If you use last unique key you won't know that an existing row changed...

Can you explain more fully the usecase for this?   Trying to think of some sort of crazy performance issue that this could resolve!

Comment: I resolved it in SOLR 1.4, while passing parameters through request. In 1.3 this functionality was also available, but there were some bugs. In 1.4 it is working very well. Now i'm passing unique key value through request.